# one liner for entering the most recently accessed subdirectory under a directory

Tags: bash

I have an unsatisfied solution like:

```
tmp=$(ls -lrt | tail -l) |  awk '{ print $NF }')
cd $tmp
```

I think there must be one-line like better solution there, so pop the question here.

Comment: Well, just removing the variable makes it a oneliner.

Comment: And you have a stray round bracket after `tail -1`

Comment: And just giving `-t` gives you sorting by *modification time*, not access time (that'd be `--time=atime -t`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `find`:

```
tmp=`find ./*/ -maxdepth 0 | xargs stat -c '%n %X' | \
   sort -r -k2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -1`
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
cd $(ls -tF |grep -m1 '/$')
```

GNU grep and coreutils need, I afraid, because of `ls -F` and `grep -m1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd `ls -du */.|head -1`
```

or

```
read < <(ls -du */.); cd $REPLY
```